# Compare O(n!) and O(3 ^ (n * log(n)))

Tags: математика

I need a help. How to compare O(n!) and O(3 ^ (n * log(n))).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `O(n!)` больше.

Comment: @Yaant обратите внимание, человек спрашивает **как** сравнить, а не **каков** результат сравнения.

Comment: предел посчитать

Comment: @Yaant, вы так уверены ;-)

Comment: @Zhihar вот ведь. :( Был уверен, однако собирался еще дополнительно прикинуть на бумажке, но тут навалилась работа. Теперь вижу, что поспешил с комментарием. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я, конечно, прошу прощения у Zhihar, но для O() надо рассматривать не просто отношение меньше/больше, а пределы. Или доказывать, что какое бы конкретное число мы ни прибавили к сумме слева, она все равно при больших n будет меньше правого выражения.
Прошу прощения, что от руки, но набирать столько — слишком долго...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

```
O(n!) < O(3 ^ (n * log(n))
```

Доказательство:

в качестве доказательства можно рассмотреть следующие выражения:

`log3(n!)` и `log3(3^(n*log(n))`

откуда

```
log3(1) + log3(2) + log3(3) + ... + log3(n)
```

против

```
n * log3(n)
```

поскольку

```
log3(1) < log3(n)
log3(2) < log3(n)
log3(3) < log3(n)

log3(n-1) < log3(n)
```

очевидно, что

```
log3(1) + log3(2) + log3(3) + ... + log3(n) < n * log3(n), n -> inf
```

и

```
n! < 3 ^ (n * log(n), n -> inf
```

доказано

Comment: *степенная функция от основания большего единицы всегда больше факториал* При всем уважении, здесь играет роль именно **логарифм**. Для чисто степенной `O(3^n) < O(n!)`, но `O(3^(n*log(n)) > O(n!)`...

Comment: да, виноват, исправил

Comment: И еще вдогонку... Играет роль еще и 3. Вернее, соотношение `O(a^(n*log(n)) > O(n!)` — справедливо только при `a > e`, а при `a < e` получаем обратное отношение...